# Calculate total elapsed time of Promises till reject?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I want to test how much requests i can do and get their total time elapsed. My `Promise` function

```
async execQuery(response, query) {
    let request = new SQL.Request();

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request.query(query, (error, result) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And my `api`

```
app.get('/api/bookings/:uid', (req, res) => {
    let st = new stopwatch();
    let id = req.params.uid;

    let query = `SELECT * FROM booking.TransactionDetails WHERE UID='${id}'`;
    for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        st.start();
        db.execQuery(res, query);
    }
});
```

I can't stop the `for` loop since its `async` but I also don't know how can I stop executing other calls after the one which first rejects so i can get the counter and the elapsed time of all successful promises. How can i achieve that?

Comment: You don't want to build SQL like this. https://xkcd.com/327/ Start using parameterized queries.

Comment: @Tomalak I know, It will be changed, but I want to achieve this first.

Comment: But when you want to measure how many requests you can do, you want to use the same method that will be used in production. What's the point in measuring something you are not going to use? And what's more, what's the point in measuring how often you can run the *exact same* query?

Comment: I want to stress the server and get all the succesful requests till timeouts

Comment: I don't think it works like that. Your webserver determines the timeout for the request, not your database server. And that timeout is a configuration value - you can look it up, you don't need to test it.

Comment: Ok so, how can I stress the database?

Comment: By the time it asynchronously rejects a promise, *all* your queries have already been started. You cannot "stop" them. Or does `request` have a `stop()` method or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create a composable wrapper for this, or a subclass:

#### Inheritance:

```
class TimedPromise extends Promise {
  constructor(executor) {
    this.startTime = performance.now(); // or Date.now
    super(executor);
    let end = () => this.endTime = performance.now(); 
    this.then(end, end); // replace with finally when available
  }
  get time() {
    return this.startTime - this.endTime; // time in milliseconds it took
  }
}
```

Then you can use methods like:

```
TimedPromise.all(promises);
TimedPromise.race(promises);

var foo = new TimedPromise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100);
let res = await foo;
console.log(foo.time); // how long foo took
```

Plus `then` chaining would work, async functions won't (since they always return native promises).

#### Composition:

```
function time(promise) {
   var startTime = performance.now(), endTime;
   let end = () => endTime = performance.now();
   promise.then(end, end); // replace with finally when appropriate.
   return () => startTime - endTime;
}
```

Then usage is:

```
 var foo = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100);
 var timed = time(foo);
 await foo;
 console.log(timed()); // how long foo took
```

This has the advantage of working everywhere, but the disadvantage of manually having to time every promise. I prefer this approach for its explicitness and arguably nicer design.

As a caveat, since a rejection handler is attached, you have to be **100% sure** you're adding your own `.catch` or `then` handler since otherwise the error will not log to the console.

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't this work in your promise ?

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var time = Date.now();
    request.query(query, (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
            reject(error);
        } else {
            resolve(result);
        }
    });
}).then(function(r){
    //code
}).catch(function(e){
    console.log('it took : ', Date.now() - time);
});
```

Or put the .then and .catch after your db.execQuery() call

Comment: The problem is that it keeps executing other promises whos waiting after the first reject. I want when I get my first reject to stop all others.

Comment: If the status of your promises depend on the success of this one, why don't you call them inside the `then()` function (instead of `//code`) ?

Answer (score -1):

You made 2 comments that would indicate you want to stop all on going queries when a promise fails but fail to mention what `SQL` is and if `request.query` is something that you can cancel.

In your for loop you already ran all the `request.query` statements, if you want to run only one query and then the other you have to do `request.query(query).then(-=>request.query(query)).then...` but it'll take longer because you don't start them all at once.

Here is code that would tell you how long all the queries took but I think you should tell us what `SQL` is so we could figure out how to set connection pooling and caching (probably the biggest performance gainer).

```
//removed the async, this function does not await anything
//  so there is no need for async
//removed initializing request, you can re use the one created in 
//  the run function, that may shave some time off total runtime
//  but not sure if request can share connections (in that case)
//  it's better to create a couple and pass them along as their
//  connection becomes available (connection pooling)
const execQuery = (response, query, request) => 
  new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) =>
      request.query(
        query
        ,(error, result) =>
          (error)
            ? reject(error)
            : resolve(result)
      )
    );

// save failed queries and resolve them with Fail object
const Fail = function(detail){this.detail=detail;};
//  let request = new SQL.Request();
const run = (numberOfTimes) => {
  const start = new Date().getTime();
  const request = new SQL.Request();
  Promise.all(
    (x=>{
      for (let i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; i++) {
        let query = `SELECT * FROM booking.TransactionDetails WHERE UID='${i}'`;
        db.execQuery(res, query, request)
        .then(
          x=>[x,query]
          ,err=>[err,query]
        )
      }    
    })()//IIFE creating array of promises
  )
  .then(
    results => {
      const totalRuntime = new Date().getTime()-start;
      const failed = results.filter(r=>(r&&r.constructor)===Fail);
      console.log(`Total runtime in ms:${totalRuntime}
      Failed:${failed.length}
      Succeeded:${results.length-failed.length}`);
    }
  )
};

//start the whole thing with:
run(10000);
```